# Has any benchmarking been done on SAS data files (compared to a SQL database)?

Tags: sql, sas, benchmarking, data-warehouse

I work for a company that's currently using a collection of SAS data files (sas7bdat) as their data warehouse. I'm trying to make the case that moving from SAS to a SQL database would result in large performance gains. Based on how long SAS is currently taking to perform queries I have a gut feeling that a data warehouse in, say, PostgreSQL running on the same hardware would be much faster.

The problem is that it's really difficult to compare performance apples-to-apples (e.g. on the same hardware). I would love to fire up a VM on my home server and run the same set of operations on SAS and compare to a SQL db, but I'm not willing to pay for SAS's expensive licensing.

Has anyone done benchmarking on how long it takes to perform a query on a SAS dataset as compared to a SQL table?

Comment: Why not just fire up Postgres at work transfer some data over and see for yourself?  There are too many variables that would change the answer.  I don't know much about SAS but there might be optimizations there to do, the pg setup might be suboptimal so it might look worse but it's really the fault of the dba.

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't any SQL databases currently installed on the server used at work, and because this server contains financial data and PII it's locked down heavily by IT. The company has only paid for one SAS license so that's the only server with SAS on it that I could use for testing, and I'm not sure they'd allow that.

Comment: It may depend on how big and important the data warehouse is as well. A database usually also requires a DBA to set up, monitor and tune and there is additional overhead there. There are other reasons besides speed, such as auditing, masking of data, better security controls, better back ups and restoring usually as well. Easier to implement data quality as well.

Comment: @Dacromir BTW, consider using Sqlite storage vs sas7bdat. IT might go for that and it is a direct replacement (single file). It requires very little to use and offers dramatic improvements.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a server administration question, not a programming question.

Comment: Even if this were on topic here, it would not be a good question, because it's not answerable - there's too many unknowns.  Sometimes SAS7BDAT is a fine solution, superior to SQL Server or similar.  Sometimes it's far worse.  It just depends on the use case - how large the datasets are, how frequently accessed, how many users access them... call SAS and ask them to do an evaluation, they have no problem telling you to use RDBMS if it's the right solution.  (Or, better, move to Viya - the CAS data store Is many orders of magnitude more efficient, since it's in memory.)

Comment: Large performance gains in SAS can be made in several ways such as adding indices to data sets, using hashes in your coding, proper use of DROP= KEEP= in queries, right sizing character column widths (don't use CHAR(2000) to store CHAR(1) data), using SAS feature `PROC FEDSQL`, or the *SAS Scalable Performance Data (SPD) Server* product.

Comment: The question here pertained to a data warehouse so I assume these aren't small SAS datasets. I don't see a use case where sas7bdat is the right long-term storage. If the client doesn't have SAS, they are locked in a closed, binary format. You can use ODBC/OLEDB to read them with limitations. SAS7BDAT is ok for temp files but that is about the extent. I am hard-pressed to think of an exception for long-term sas7bdat use.

Answer (score 2):

I have done that analysis before, as a consultant. I don't have the specifics in front of me but it is enormous (SQL Server is like 10-100x faster). Create the table using an index.

As a former SAS consultant (at SAS), we used to encourage clients to use an RDBMS vs SAS datasets. The sas7bdat is a proprietary, binary format designed a long time ago. It is nowhere near the speed or capability of an RDBMS.

Also, it is easy to convert from SAS datasets to a SQL table.

I am not sure how Postgres would perform but I would imagine the numbers would be comparable to SQL Server (probably not as fast but pretty close). I have used all of the major DBs but I tested on SQL Server.

Comment: Indeed, my current customer words with SAS libraries refering Db2 databases, an option that also gives much control over access rights. Columnar databases give even better performance for most analytical tasks. We are currently evaluating SingleStore.

Comment: Agreed on using RDBMS or other ways of storing data. sas7bdat files are convenient for temp tables and small tables, but they get quite slow when you're looking at large transactional datasets in the hundreds of GB. SAS will handle it just fine, but you'll spend a lot of time waiting. I highly recommend using SAS/ACCESS engines and RDBMS instead. You'll save a ton of time.